# Going to Top of Page , when we click tab link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm desinging vertical tab using javascript, vertical tab working fine, but the page not showing header.

### HTML:

```
 <ul>
    <li><a href="#a1">a1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#b1">b1</a></li>          
    </ul>
    <div id="sections">
    <div class="section" id="a">
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="b">
    </div>
```

My demo link: http://www.bajistech.info/tiltindicators.html#TiltWatch-Plus1, I'm trying to make page scroll when I click on the vertical tab.

### Script 1:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){

    if (
        $('ul#verticalNav li a').length &&
        $('div.section').length
    ) {
        $('div.section').css( 'display', 'none' );
        //$('ul#verticalNav li a').each(function() {
        $('ul#verticalNav li a').click(function() { 
            showSection( $(this).attr('href') );
        });
  // if hash found then load the tab from Hash id
        if(window.location.hash) 
        {
   // to get the div id
           showSection( window.location.hash);
        }
        else // if no hash found then default first tab is opened
        {
            $('ul#verticalNav li:first-child a').click();
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

### Script 2

```
function showSection( sectionID ) {
    $('div.section').css( 'display', 'none' );
    $('div'+sectionID).css( 'display', 'block' );
}
$(document).ready(function(){

    if (
        $('ul#verticalNav li a').length &&
        $('div.section').length
    ) {
        $('div.section').css( 'display', 'none' );
        //$('ul#verticalNav li a').each(function() { // no need for each loop
        $('ul#verticalNav li a').click(function() { // Use $('ul#verticalNav li a').click
            showSection( $(this).attr('href') );
        });
        //});
        if(window.location.hash) // if hash found then load the tab from Hash id
        {
           showSection( window.location.hash);// to get the div id
        }
        else // if no hash found then default first tab is opened
        {
            $('ul#verticalNav li:first-child a').click();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to accept the event in your `click` handler, and call `event.preventDefault()` to stop the browser from following your link to `"#"`.

If you actually want your links to take you to a part of the page, you need their IDs to match. An href of `"#a1"` is never going to take you to a div with id `"a"`. The *whole* ID has to match, not just part of it. Your script suffers from the same problem. Your hrefs are `#a1` and `#b1`, and your divs have IDs of `a` and `b`. Why would you add `1`? What is that `1` supposed to do? The href and the ID have to be *the same* for the code you've written to link the a/div together.

Comment: Hi meagar, if i add the event.preventDefault(), i'm not able to see the url like this  : http://www.bajistech.info/tiltindicators1.html#img ,

Comment: you can set the `window.location.hash` like `window.location.hash = '#test'`